# How to found which timer job throwing Login failure error for deleted search db and how to delete orphaned timer jobs for old serarch service

Tags: 2013, 2010, timer-jobs, enterprise-search

Deleted search service crawl database login failed error in all servers

SQL Database 'Search_CrawlStoreDB' on SQL Server instance '' not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Cannot open database "Search_CrawlStoreDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user ''.

- we deleted old search service application
- search components properly deployed in new search service application now
  -we cleared configuration cache from all servers.
  how can we found which timer job throwing this error and how to delete orphaned timer jobs for old search service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve by below link
https://shipoint.com/tag/fixing-error-cannot-open-database-search_service_application_db_-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-domainusername/

i used Get-SPDatabase and checked which search db is not responding and deleted.